# Razor syntax in separate js file

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a script file, `script.js` that holds all the javascript for a given page.  In there, I do some ajax `POST` methods and generate an HTML view from the response.  There are certain buttons that I want to be shown if the current user is an admin / hidden if the current user is not an admin.

How can I add Razor syntax in `success: function () {};` to display / hide those buttons?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking​​ for [RazorJS](http://nuget.org/packages/RazorJS).

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore. Would recommend using NuGet to obtain the library

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to add to SLaks' answer a few more details that made it hard for me to use RazorJS.

After installing it with the Package Manager as explained [here](http://nuget.org/packages/RazorJS), you should add in your razor view the following line:

```
@Html.RazorJSInclude("~/Scripts/my_javascript_file.js")
```

And then all your razor code will work just fine!